# ruby which data structure to use

Tags: ruby, data-structures

I'm working with Ripper sexp expressions, it looks like this:

```
[:program,
 [[:class,
   [:const_ref, [:@const, "A", [1, 6]]],
   nil,
   [:bodystmt,
    [[:class,
      [:const_ref, [:@const, "B", [1, 15]]],
      nil,
      [:bodystmt,
       [[:def,
         [:@ident, "test", [1, 22]],
         [:params, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil],
         [:bodystmt, [[:void_stmt]], nil, nil, nil]]],
       nil,
       nil,
       nil]]],
    nil,
    nil,
    nil]]]]
```

And i'm using array as path to get element in sexp expression. For example

```
path = [1,0,1,1]   =>   sexp[1][0][1][1]
```

will get me

```
[:@const, "A", [1, 6]]
```

With this path I can get next, previous, parent elements and so on.

But I'm wondering is there a data structure which more suitable for this kind of tasks?

Comment: A tree, because that's what sexps are.

Comment: All tree data structures which I've met were for sorting, how to have path to element, get parent element?

Comment: [Try this](http://blogorama.nerdworks.in/arbit/webstuff/lisp-graph.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the obvious trees, you may want to look at zippers:

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipper_(data_structure)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipper_%28data_structure%29)

Someone recently implemented form-zip for Clojure, if you want to look at an example:

https://github.com/GeorgeJahad/form-zip

Comment: good point about zipper, thanks. I found ruby implementation of Zipper https://gist.github.com/4357/f3f4aa27e97b8389b8360715772478b88dd2c030. Could you tell me will this implementation work on sexp expression?

Comment: form-zip is for Clojure forms and since Clojure is a Lisp, forms are sexps. That's why I posted it as an example.

Comment: I happen to have a Ruby zipper implementation lying around: https://github.com/frankshearar/zipr which can zip over arbitrary hierarchical structures, like the Clojure implementation.